# Show that an $m \times n$ matrix gives rise to a well-defined map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Show that an $m \times n$ matrix gives rise to a well-defined map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$.

I was thinking of mapping rows to columns of the matrix. Let $$M = \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & \dots  & a_{1n} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & \dots  & a_{2n} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    a_{m1} & a_{m2} & a_{m3} & \dots  & a_{mn}
\end{bmatrix},$$ then must we know if there are more columns than rows in order to create such a map?

Answer (score 2):

Not at all. The (linear) mapping is simply
\begin{align*}
\mathbf R^n&\longrightarrow\mathbf R^m \\
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\\vdots\\x_n
\end{bmatrix}&\longmapsto M\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\\vdots\\x_n
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}x_1+\dots+a_{1n}x_n\\\vdots\\ a_{m1}x_1+\dots+a_{mn}x_n
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Comment: How do we know this is well-defined?

Comment: It's obvious: a vector in $\mathbf R^n$ is a list of $n$ real numbers, and the coefficients $a_{ij}$ are given.

Comment: It's well-defined because the $a_{ij}$ are uniquely determined by the matrix $M$ (recall that two $m\times n$ matrices $M = (a_{ij}),M' = (a'_{ij})$ are equal if and only if $a_{ij} = a'_{ij}$ for every $i,j$ pair), and multiplication and addition are well-defined operations on $\Bbb R$, and it clearly sends an element of $\Bbb R^n$ to one living in $\Bbb R^m$